# Prevent database corrupt when save because of bad WiFi connection

Tags: php, mysql, connection

Some users have bad WiFi connection when using our system because of geography or internet provider issue. When some user save some product info, i found some data(field) not 100% save into DB. And this is very difficult to me to reproduce the problem because my connection is good.

So my question is how to let server know that i already send all field to process before save/update query execute ?

```
case "save":

for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($languages); $i<$n; $i++)
{
    $language_id = $languages[$i]['id'];
    $name = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', tep_db_prepare_input($_POST["products_name"][$language_id]));
    $description = tep_db_prepare_input(str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $_POST["products_description"][$language_id]));
    $extra_info = tep_db_prepare_input(str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $_POST["products_extra_info"][$language_id]));

    tep_db_perform(TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION, $sql_data_array, 'update', 'products_id = "' . $pID . '" AND language_id="'.$language_id.'"');

    // update other language that empty
    $sql_data_array = array('products_name' => $name);
    tep_db_perform(TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION, $sql_data_array, 'update', 'products_id = "'.$pID.'" and products_name = ""');

    $sql_data_array = array('products_description' => $description);
    tep_db_perform(TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION, $sql_data_array, 'update', 'products_id = "'.$pID.'" and products_description = ""');

    $sql_data_array = array('products_extra_info' => $extra_info);
    tep_db_perform(TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION, $sql_data_array, 'update', 'products_id = "'.$pID.'" and products_extra_info = ""');
}

 ... etc
```

Comment: Use database __transactions__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using database transaction you can prevent these errors. 
When something goes wrong no update will be performed to the DB.
Note that you can't use transactions on MyISAM tables, you need to use the **InnoDB** Engine

Comment: as i check our DB is using MyISAM, any option for this situation ?

Comment: MyISAM is faster than InnoDB but doesn't guarantee a high level of data protection on errors. If you don't need high performance, try to convert tables to InnoDB engine:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `transaction` to perform multiple DB queries. The advantage is that if one of the query fails in the execution, all of the previous that were executed get undone in the database. That way you don't have any corrupted or incomplete data in your DB.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the obvious as stated by @Mark Baker, you could use PHP's [connection_aborted()](https://www.php.net/connection-aborted) function to detect when a user disconnects. Here's an excerpt from the comments section:

--

A trick to detecting if a connection is closed without having to send data that will otherwise corrupt the stream of data (like a binary file) you can use a combination of chunking the data on HTTP/1.1 by sending a "0" ("zero") as a leading chunk size without anything else.

*NOTE* it's important to note that it's not a good idea to check the stream more then once every few seconds. By doing this you are potentially increasing the data sent to the user with no gain to the user.

A good reason to do it this way is if you are generating a report that takes a long time to run and takes a lot of server resources. This would allow the server to detect if a user canceled the download and do any cleanup without corrupting the file file being download.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
header('Transfer-Encoding:chunked');
ob_flush();
flush();
$start = microtime(true);
$i = 0;
// Use this function to echo anything to the browser.
function vPrint($data){
    if(strlen($data))
        echo dechex(strlen($data)), "\r\n", $data, "\r\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
// You MUST execute this function after you are done streaming information to the browser.
function endPacket(){
    echo "0\r\n\r\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
do{
    echo "0";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    if(connection_aborted()){
        // This happens when connection is closed
        file_put_contents('/tmp/test.tmp', sprintf("Conn Closed\nTime spent with connection open: %01.5f sec\nLoop itterations: %s\n\n", microtime(true) - $start, $i), FILE_APPEND);
        endPacket();
        exit;
    }
    usleep(50000);
    vPrint("I get echo'ed every itteration (every .5 second)<br />\n");
}while($i++ < 200);
endPacket();
?
```

**Note: This line `ignore_user_abort(true);` allows the script to continue running in the background after the user disconnects, without it (i.e. by default) the PHP process is killed instantly. This is why using transactions will solve your problem as the transaction that was started, never completed.**